# Overwriting the css property of an external java script file not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to overwrite the styling of an element in an external java-script file.

If I paste this code into a local file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6343621/">New Poll</a></noscript>

<style>
.pds-links {
    display: inline !important;
}
</style>
```

and run within Google chrome I receive this error on inspection on the class '.pds-links' :

[image]

The css property is correct as when I run this code in a fiddle all of the elements display inline : 
http://jsfiddle.net/YsEmj/

How can I successfully overwrite the 'display' property of the .pds-links style? Is the reason this is occurring that the javascript file is being loaded before the .css property can be applied to it, if this is the case do I need to use jQuery to update the style ?

Comment: What does it mean for an element to be in an external JavaScript file? I don't think that has anything at all to do with it, in any case.

Comment: Is the css for .pds-links being set from the JS file originally?

Comment: you could change your selector to use IDs instead of classes, as the ID will take higher priority than anything else.

Comment: What's shown in the error console?

Comment: @Pointy I _think_ OP is saying the element is dynamically inserted into the DOM by the JS, in which case the question becomes "does the CSS from the <style> tag in the original HTML get re-applied to new elements in the DOM".  But you're saying it will?

Comment: If you check the "computed style" section in Chrome (above where you're already looking) it'll tell you what "display" attribute is applied, and where it's being applied from.

Comment: @Billy Moat yes the css is being set within the JS file originally

Comment: @Pointy there is an error on console but its within the script file and I dont think should be related to this issue, error is : GET http://s3.wordpress.com/wp-admin/images/white-grad.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Sepster thanks, but how does this help me ? I am unable to modify the original JS file.

Comment: Try adding the css file after the JS file on the page. Also try being more specfic with your css declaration e.g. body #container #left .pds-links (obviously using the elements from your page).

Comment: OP, are you asking me how knowing the computed style helps?  If you can see the rule being applied (and hence the selectors), you can at least try mimicing them in _your_ style declaration to make them more specific (similar to what Billy Moat is saying, I think) which should then take precedence, assuming @Pointy is correct in (what I understood to be) his assertion that JS vs. CSS order is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes I think it's the stylesheet ordering probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by overriding all of the values generated by the style. The script generates this style :

```
.pds-links {padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;display: block;text-align: center;}
```

Using this style causes the all of the items to appear inline :

```
.pds-links {padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;display: inline !important; text-align: center;}
```

I'm not sure why the style does not get utilized when I just override the display property : .pds-links `{ display: inline !important; }` I may a separate question to address this.

Answer (score 1):

The poll script is adding a `style` tag to the end of the `head`. If your stylesheet comes before it, and their style also specifies `!important` it will override your style.

Here's the gunk the script is adding:

```
<style type="text/css" id="poll_style6343621">#PDI_container6343621 .pds-box{font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;background: #fff;border: 1px solid #ccc;width: 300px;font-size: 12px;text-align: left;color: #4e4e4e;-webkit-border-radius: 12px;-moz-border-radius: 12px;border-radius: 12px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-box A{outline: none;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-clear{display: block;clear: both;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-box-outer{padding: 12px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-question-top{font-size:14px;line-height: 120%;color: #333;font-weight: bold;padding: 5px 0px 15px 0px;position:relative;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer{padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;border-top: 1px solid #e8e8e8;border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer label{color: #333;font-size: 13px;line-height: 150%;position: relative;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer-group{display: block;padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer-group BR{display: none;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer-input{display: block;float:left;width: 25px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-input-label{display: block;float:left;width: 245px;cursor: pointer;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer-other{padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-textfield{background: #FFF;border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;font-size: 12px;padding: 2px;width: 150px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer-other BR{display: none;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-other-label{display: block;float:left;cursor: pointer;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-feedback-group{display: block;padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-feedback-label{display: block;padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-feedback-result {float:right;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer-text {float:left} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-feedback-per{font-weight: bold;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-feedback-votes{font-weight: normal;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer-feedback {background-color: #f1f1f1;border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;position: relative;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-answer-feedback-bar {font-size: 2px;background: #3478e3;height: 18px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-vote {padding: 10px 0px;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-votebutton-outer {} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-vote BR{display: none;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-vote-button {color: #464646;padding: 3px 25px;white-space: nowrap;background:#F2F2F2 url(http://s3.wordpress.com/wp-admin/images/white-grad.png) repeat-x scroll left top;-webkit-border-radius: 11px;-moz-border-radius:11px;border-radius: 11px;border: 1px solid #999;cursor: pointer;font-size: 12px;font-family: "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial;text-decoration: none;line-height: 25px;font-weight: bold;white-space: nowrap;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-vote-button:hover{border: 1px solid #333;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-vote-button-load {color: #464646;padding: 3px 25px;white-space: nowrap;-webkit-border-radius: 11px;-moz-border-radius:11px;border-radius: 11px;border: 1px solid #999;cursor: pointer;font-size: 12px;font-family: "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial;text-decoration: none;line-height: 25px;font-weight: bold;white-space: nowrap;background:#EEE url(http://i.polldaddy.com/polls/vote-loader-eeeeee.gif) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-vote-button-load SPAN{visibility: hidden;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-links {padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;display: block;text-align: center;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-links-back {padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;display: block;text-align: center;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-links A {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color: #4e4e4e;text-decoration: none;padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;line-height: 24px;display: inline-block;font-weight: bold;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-links-back A {font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color: #4e4e4e;text-decoration: none;padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px;line-height: 24px;display: inline-block;font-weight: bold;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-links A:hover {text-decoration: underline;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-links-back A:hover {text-decoration: underline;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-comments SPAN{font-weight: normal;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-total-votes{padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;position: relative;} #PDI_container6343621 .pds-total-votes SPAN{font-weight: bold;} #PDI_container6343621 div {margin:0;padding:0;}</style>
```

Comment: should it not also not display using jsfiddle, as this fiddle displays as I expect, it is overriding the style : http://jsfiddle.net/YsEmj/

Comment: In the fiddle, you are adding your script tag to the `body`, after this generated script in the `head`.